# HalconDotNet - Check if Halcon variable is empty or uninitialized

Tags: c#, halcon

Is there a proper way of checking if a variable is uninitialized or empty?
As a workaround I've been comparing with results from `gen_empty_obj` to see if its empty, but I have no idea how to check if a variable was initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some basic checks, using try-catch statement. Made two scenarios for demo, but you could wrap those checks in a procedure to make it more readable.

```
* Results of 'testObject' checks
testObject_IsEmpty := true
testObject_IsInitialized := true

* Results of 'testRegion' checks
testRegion_IsEmpty := true
testRegion_IsInitialized := true


***
* Test scenario #1 :: 'testObject' and 'testRegion' are not initialized for some reason.
*
***

* Added this if-statement to make it possible to compile the code.
* The 'testObject' and 'testRegion' will be visible but not initialized
if (false)
    gen_empty_obj (testObject)
    gen_empty_region (testRegion)
endif

* Try-catch will throw an exception when the variables are not initialized.
* otherwise, the try-statement will run correctly and assign if the variables are empty.
try
    count_obj (testObject, count)
    testObject_IsEmpty := count <= 0
    
    area_center (testRegion, area, _, _)
    testRegion_IsEmpty := area <= 0
catch (Exception)
    testObject_IsInitialized := false
    testRegion_IsInitialized := false
endtry

stop()
***
* Test scenario #2 :: 'testObject' and 'testRegion' are initialized, but they are empty.
*
***

* Initialize 'testObject' and 'testRegion', but they are still empty.
gen_empty_obj (testObject)
gen_empty_region (testRegion)

* Try-catch will throw an exception when the variables are not initialized.
* otherwise, the try-statement will run correctly and assign if the variables are empty.
try
    count_obj (testObject, count)
    testObject_IsEmpty := count <= 0
    
    area_center (testRegion, area, _, _)
    testRegion_IsEmpty := area <= 0
catch (Exception)
    testObject_IsInitialized := false
    testRegion_IsInitialized := false
endtry
```